# Create NxN matrix mathematica

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

Having a bit of trouble generating an NxN matrix in Mathematica. Given the value of N, I need to construct the NxN matrix that looks like the following:

[image: NxN matrix]

```
N = Input["Enter value for N:"];
matrix = ConsantArray[0,{N,N}];
Do[matrix[[i,j]] =   **"???"**  ,{i,N}, {j,N}]
matrix // Matrix Form
```

Not sure in what should go as my statement in Do-Loop. Any help would appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a 1D array [1 ... n<sup>2</sup>] and then reshape or partition it to a matrix.

```
matrix = ArrayReshape[Range[n^2], {n, n}]

(* also works: *)
matrix = Partition[Range[n^2], n]
```

Answer (score 3):

a couple more ways.

```
matrix=Table[j+(i-1) n,{i,n},{j,n}]

matrix=Array[#2+(#1-1) n &,{n,n}]
```

the `Table` form should give a clue how to fix your `Do` as well, but that's usually a poor approach performance-wise.

do not use capital `N` by the way its a reserved symbol.